# Since i install the vue extension in vs code my snippets from emmet appear twice ._., anybody know why

Tags: html, vue.js, code-snippets, emmet

as you can see:
I don't know , but if when i uninstall the extension that's fixed; by the way that only happens with html.

This is the extension:
[image: extension vue]

strange behavior

[image: strange behavior_1]

[image: strange behavior_2]

in default look like this (default):

[image: default behavior_1]

[image: default behavior_2]

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the HTML written inside of the `template` tag is considered as HTML by emmet to, while it's `vue-html`.

It's probably a bug from the library, minor one.
You have already created [an issue there](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1939), so there is not much to do now.

Maybe give a try to some configurations in this thread: https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/716#issuecomment-975378571

Or that one: https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1852

Looking with the keyword `duplicate` or `Emmet` will give you quite some leads overall.